# .NET problems with using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, connection

I have a .NET desktop core 5.0 application where I use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client to connect to an Oracle Database.

It works fine for me, but there are a couple of users that can't connect to the database via the application. The user is the same and the password is gathered from an Azure KeyVault, i.e. connection strings are identical whether I run the app or they do.

As I understand using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client should work regardless of what is installed locally on your computer - but I might be wrong here.

I normally connect to MS SQL databases, so I am not really familiar with the nuget package and nor do I know what the usual issues are, so please forgive me if I have left out important information.

Let me know if I should provide any further details.

Thanks in advance.

**---------------UPDATE------------------**

So it turns out it is not the connection that fails, but the extract itself. And the error I get is:

ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Again, please keep in mind that it works for some users.

Comment: I would start looking for the error message received by these clients. And if you know it please add it to your post

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks for taking the time - much appreciated. Please see error code in updated information above.

Comment: This issue was due to a missing to_date(x,y) in the query for oracle db. Probably due to some local settings, this worked for me, but not for others.

Comment: Does the date column in Oracle allow nulls?  This error could be because you are trying to convert to a date with a null parameter.  I have often had issues with dates, so I usually try and return them in a consistent format from oracle (`to_char(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')`) and then handle it with a tryparse locally in code.